# React Native Image with Headers failing to load in Android

Tags: react-native, image, oauth-2.0, expo

While trying to access protected images I came across the implementation from React Native's side of using source property with headers. But this approach has a problem with Android devices. It loads perfectly on iOS but when going to Android devices I believe the headers with the token are not being sent properly

At first I thought that the token was not being passed properly, but as you can see in the following code it is properly being sent

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Image, ImageBackground } from "react-native";

import { getAuth } from "../services/auth/auth.js";

const ImageWithToken = ({ imageType, uri, defaultImage, ...rest }) => {
  const [newUri, setNewUri] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      const tok = await getAuth();
      if (!tok) getToken();
      setNewUri({
        uri: uri,
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + tok?.access_token },
      });
    };

    getToken();

    return () => {
      console.log("Cleanup");
    };
  }, []);

  if (!newUri) {
    console.log("There is no token");
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("im here")}
      {imageType === "imageBackground" ? (
         <ImageBackground
           source={uri ? newUri : defaultImage}
           {...rest}
         ></ImageBackground>
      ) : (
        <Image source={uri ? newUri : defaultImage} {...rest}></Image>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageWithToken;
```

The method getAuth provides with the logged in token of the application.
I came across several posts informing of React Native failures with Image Headers as in [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33131) and I wanted to confirm that the problems where coming from it rather than from my code, and if there are other alternatives as I have to load an Image carousel. To clarify the project is being built with Expo
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several checks and updates thanks to [Dustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11729637/dustin-forsyth) I realized there was a possibility to use expo-image upgrading the project to Expo SDK 48 (Checkout this [post](https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-image-being-unavailable-in-expo-go-and-snack-yet/70199)), even though it was not specified the library was available since that version without using development builds(necessary for our project). Aside from this, the manual upgrade of the library was needed to the latest version as it provided ImageBackground properties, as the ones found in React Native's library by default but with the proper implementation for Headers. Due to this a warning was triggered as Expo was expecting a different library version for expo-image. This allowed us to build without errors, just the warning mentioned before. So for anyone having the same problem I hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I might be remembering wrong on this but I seem to remember that the issue was that android requires the accept type to be set in the headers for it to work correctly. Try this and see if it works for you:

```
  setNewUri({
    uri: uri,
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + tok?.access_token, Accept: "image/jpg" },
  });
```

obviously this is assuming you are using jpg images. Here is a link to some different mime types for the Accept Header if you need something different: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: I have tried with the accept type too and sending more headers to be more specific but it seems the output is the same.

Comment: Have you tried just hardcoding the headers and the uri instead of actually getting them via the getToken()? Just trying to discount some other issue with maybe state updates or something else. I have this working in on of my apps so it seems unlikely that it wouldn't work for you unless this is a bug in a specific version of React Native.

Comment: Yes, the test was done also with hardcoded values. It is having the same output as with it coming from functions. The problem is not of an asynchronous type

Comment: Dang I am at a loss then. Have you tried a network inspector so see if the headers are actually attached? I use https://proxyman.io to proxy my network traffic so I can verify my network calls are what I expect them to be.

Comment: I have gotten to the point where with a common get of the Blob and afterwards introducing it inside the source the information is properly retrieved, but when using React Native's headers approach it is failing

Comment: So I just looked back at my code and realized that I am actually not doing this. I thought I had some that were using auth headers with the React Native Image but I don't. I am currently using https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image for images that have authorizations. I plan to switch over to this one though https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image/

Comment: Yeah, that was my main course of action but as I'm using Expo it entered in conflict and I don't know if I can eject expo for the development build as required. Thanks for the effort btw

Comment: You should be able to use the expo image one in a managed expo app I would try that. I linked to it above as well its the expo link.

Comment: I will do it. The only thing is I will have to upgrade 2 sdks. Wish me luck. Thank you so much!